# How to change directories in ubuntu using bash shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I was trying to use cd in shell script to change directories . But it's not happening ? Why is it so ? What can be the other ways to change the directories in shell script ?

Comment: How you are calling cd??

Comment: also: http://askubuntu.com/q/481715